# How to solve error of html display in front end while changing theme in wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, web, wordpress-theming, themes, custom-wordpress-pages

I have created a website for blogging using WordPress platform but it is taking more loading time and having some errors. I use newspaper theme. I am trying to customize new theme for my site but somehow some html code is appeared at front-end after customizing any other theme.

Sitename: http://www.komalseo21.com

Theme used: newspaper

Check the snap @ site - image with error

[image: Site image with error]

Answer (score 1):

The HTML code at the front-end you mentioned are the unparsed shortcodes from the other theme. Your new theme doesn't have them, so they simply get outputed in raw format.

Here is an [article](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/05/02/dealing-with-shortcode-madness) that describes your problem in more detail.

> Users, here’s what theme developers are not telling you: By using
>   their theme’s shortcodes, they are essentially locking you into using
>   their themes forever.

You could try to copy the shortcode code to the new theme, but that would probably not be enough. You will most likely also have to import styles too.